# Como utilizar .env em publicações no NPM?

Tags: npm, variáveis-de-ambiente

Estou tentando publicar um pacote npm com um arquivo `.env` utilizando o pacote [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Quando testo localmente utilizando o `process.env.MINHA_PROPRIEDADE`, ele funciona normalmente, porém, quando eu tento utilizar instalando o pacote publicado globalmente, ele não funciona.

Já tentei alterar o conteúdo do `.gitignore` para não incluir o .env, mas isso não resolveu o problema.

É possível eu utilizar uma variável de ambiente quando publico um pacote no NPM? Se sim, onde estou errando?

O código que eu estou utilizando é o seguinte:

```
require('dotenv').config()
function main() {
  console.log(`A chave é ${process.env.MINHA_VARIAVEL}`)
}

main()
```

E meu arquivo `.env` tem o seguinte:

```
MINHA_VARIAVEL=TESTE
```

Basicamente, esse é um pacote para testar como fazer isso...

O que acontece quando executo localmente é a impressão no console da frase "A chave é TESTE", já quando publico e instalo globalmente, o retorno que recebo é "A chave é undefined".

Comment: Você tem o exemplo de código para clarear o que está fazendo?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei com um código de exemplo

Comment: Não será que o teu programa está tentando acessar o .env de outro local quando publica, porque neste caso o pacote é instalado nos modules. Estou apenas supondo, não afirmando ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento era isso mesmo, tive que alterar o config e adicionar o parâmetro `{path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env')}` pra resolver o problema. Coloca isso como resposta pra eu aceitar (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente o local do caminho que a lib irá procurar quando instalado no `npm_modules` será diferente de quando testa o script direto, portanto para resolver isto use o path.resolve:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#path

Ficando algo como (como o próprio [Felipe Avelar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1333/felipe-avelar) descobriu):

```
{ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env'), ... }
```

No exemplo foi combinado ao `__dirname` (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname), mas dependendo poderia usar o `process.cwd()`

- https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_cwd

No caso de `process.cwd()` este vai pegar o caminho de onde o script é executado e não o caminho de onde ele se encontra, ou seja se for um script global e você executar em uma pasta diferente ele vai poder ler os envs de variadas pastas (que estiver no momento), mas isto depende da necessidade.

Comment: No caso, o problema era que o dotenv buscava, justamente, no `process.cwd()`, mas o .env, por estar instalado globalmente, precisava que eu acessasse o ponto onde o arquivo script era executado, por isso usei o `__dirname` e funcionava localmente, pelo fato do `__dirname` ser igual ao `process.cwd()` quando executado localmente. (: